# Getting \u2026 when storing a value in a varchar field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am seeing  the last three trailing dots in my entered value is getting converted to \u2026.

**Eg - SampleString... gets converted to SampleString\u2026**

Any idea why this happens and how to resolve it?

Comment: This is client, not SQL server.

Comment: You've tagged this as both MySQL and Oracle; they are different database products (both owned by Oracle Corp.) Which are you using? And where did your original string value come from - if, for example, you had text in Word that might have auto-converted three periods `...` to an ellipsis `…`, and that was just copied/pasted into your database.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the dots at the end are a single Unicode character ([horizontal ellipsis](https://charbase.com/2026-unicode-horizontal-ellipsis)).

So if it's not just a display problem, maybe your varchar column has a non-unicode character set assigned?